# Is it possible to use Enumerable.Sum() extension with dynamic types?

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, telerik

In my project I am using Telerik RadGridView control, ItemSource of which is list of dynamic objects (derived from DynamicObject).
I was planning to use AggregateFunctions, like SumFunction, MinFunction, but it is crashing in columns, which are getting values from dynamic properties. If I am correct, it is because of Linq extensions, and not Telerik.
Is there any workaround for this issue?

**Update**
model class looks like this

```
public class SampleModel : DynamicObject
{
   // some properties
}
```

Source is like:

```
 myGrid.ItemsSource = new List<SampleModel> { // some model items };
```

XAML is:

```
<telerik:RadGridView ShowColumnFooters="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" x:Name="myGrid">
        <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            <telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding p1}">
                <telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
                    <telerik:SumFunction />
                </telerik:GridViewDataColumn.AggregateFunctions>
            </telerik:GridViewDataColumn>
        </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

Where *p1* is dynamic property
Exception message is:
***No generic method 'Sum' on type 'System.Linq.Enumerable' is compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.***

Comment: Please show code that reproduces the problem and exact exception (instead of "crashing in columns" statement).

Comment: @Alexei I will add sample and exception message to question as an update.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating my own aggregation function and building expression inside it manually (source: [Telerik support](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/gridview/timespan-sum-aggregation-function.aspx)).
Code for Sum() function is:

```
public class CustomSumFunction : EnumerableSelectorAggregateFunction
{
    protected override string AggregateMethodName
    {
        get { return "Sum"; }
    }

    protected override Type ExtensionMethodsType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(CustomAggregateFunctions);
        }
    }
}

public static class CustomAggregateFunctions
{
    public static TValue Sum<T, TValue>(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, TValue> selector)
    {

        return source.Select(selector).Aggregate((t1, t2) => 
            {
                Expression expr = Expression.Add(Expression.Constant(t1, t1.GetType()), Expression.Constant(t2, t2.GetType()));
                Expression conversion = Expression.Convert(expr, typeof(TValue));
                return Expression.Lambda<Func<TValue>>(conversion).Compile()();                    
            });
    }

    public static decimal? Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, decimal?> selector)
    {
        return source.Sum(selector);
    }

    public static decimal Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, decimal> selector)
    {
        return source.Sum(selector);
    }

    public static double? Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, double?> selector)
    {
        return source.Sum(selector);
    }

    public static double Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, double> selector)
    {
        return source.Sum(selector);
    }

    public static float? Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, float?> selector)
    {
        return source.Sum(selector);
    }

    public static float Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, float> selector)
    {
        return source.Sum(selector);
    }

    public static int? Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int?> selector)
    {
        return source.Sum(selector);
    }

    public static int Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, int> selector)
    {
        return source.Sum(selector);
    }

    public static long? Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, long?> selector)
    {
        return source.Sum(selector);
    }

    public static long Sum<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, long> selector)
    {
        return source.Sum(selector);
    }
}
```